# java.io.IOException: Permission denied Error when writing to removable SD card

Tags: java, android, io, permissions

I have give read and write permissions in manifest file and with code. I am able to create files in phone storage with no problems and its absolute path is `/storage/emulated/0`

But When I try to write file in my removable sdcard with file.createNewFile() to thw path `/mnt/media_rw/33A9-10F2`, it throws an error

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

It is possible to download a file from that location using Download manager. Please help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

You do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

`DownloadManager` is powered by a system app, and system apps have greater ability to work with the filesystem than do ordinary apps.

> I am able to create file in phone storage with no problems.

You do not have access to most of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps).